# multiple dropdown menus with javascript. unfortnately only by ugly "brute force" means

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I managed to build myself three drop down menus with flexboxes and some very basic JavaScript.
Because I didn't know better I used one simple function three times instead of working with parameters, variables and stuff. I'd call this an ugly and "brute force" solution.

```
<div class="menue">
<div onmouseover="open1()" onmouseout="close1()" id="menuepunkt_top">
<img src="#" alt="photography"></div>
<div onmouseover="open2()" onmouseout="close2()" id="menuepunkt_top">
<img src="#" alt="painting"></div>
<div onmouseover="open3()" onmouseout="close3()" id="menuepunkt_top">
<img src="#" alt="shoutout"></div>
</div>
```

you see the `onmouseover="open1-3"` function exists three times. That is ugly.
If you take a look at the JavaScript it becomes even more ugly. `function open1-3() {...}` and `function close 1-3() {...}`.

```
function open1() {
document.getElementById('menuepunkt_unten_1').style.opacity = '1';
}
function close1() {
document.getElementById('menuepunkt_unten_1').style.opacity = '0';
}
...
```

and not to mention the 3 huge css ids with identical content.

```
#menuepunkt_unten_1-3 {...}
```

Well it works, and you can check it out here:
http://codepen.io/einserpasch/pen/XJqxXY

but can anyone tell me how to make this more elegant?

I would like to be able to use this one JavaScript function to work on all three drop down menus if possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is most appropriate to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: While I agree that this would be on-topic at [codereview.se], being on-topic on [codereview.se] is actually **not** one of the reasons that a [so] question is off-topic.  If this question is off-topic for [so], vote to close for that reason.  If this question is more appropriate on [codereview.se], perhaps flag for a moderator to migrate.  A question should only be closed on [so] if it is off-topic on [so], not because it might also be on-topic somewhere else.

Comment: didn't know there was an actual code review section. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

base solutions include two different CSS class, one for the top menu and the other one for sub-menus and you can iterate over the CSS class of top menus and attach an onclick event handler

here you can find a step-by-step tutorial: http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/touch-friendly-drop-down-menus/